# Merging DataTables while skipping first n rows for each dataTable

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb, oledbdataadapter

The goal is to gather and put data from multiple workbooks in a single new worksheet from a new workbook that the code will create.While merging the datatables (Worksheets), i would like to skip the first 4 rows of each datatables (which are headers), before the Merging occurs. The following code mutiplies the number of datatables (Worksheets) in my foreach loop by the specified number of rows I want to skip  from each datatable (4 in this project) and then skips the result from the top of the MERGED DATATABLE. I end up with too many rows missing from the first input datatable and the headers of the other input datatables still in the MERGED DATATABLE. I've thought about using DataSets and iterating over that, but the wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Sheet1"); only takes in Datatables as a parameter. I can't convert Datasets or DataTableCollection to DataTables to make matters worse.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using ClosedXML.Excel;


namespace CompilApp
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dirALC_EDC = @"C:\_________________\";
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirALC_EDC, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    String theConnString = (String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", file));

                    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(theConnString);
                    excelConnection.Open();


                    var da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    var _command_A = new OleDbCommand();
                    string query_A = @"select * 
                    FROM [Sheet1$]";
                    _command_A.Connection = excelConnection;
                    _command_A.CommandText = query_A;
                    da.SelectCommand = _command_A;

                    da.Fill(dt);

                    IEnumerable<DataRow> newRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(4);
                    DataTable dt2 = newRows.CopyToDataTable();

                    dt.Clear();
                    dt.Merge(dt2);

                }
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Sheet1");
                wb.SaveAs(@"C:___________________.xlsx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the first 4 rows from the table before you merge it:

```
        string dirALC_EDC = @"C:\_________________\";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirALC_EDC, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        DataTable merged = new DataTable();

        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * FROM [Sheet1$]", $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={file};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"");
            da.Fill(dt);

            //remove first 4 rows
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
              dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

            merged.Merge(dt);

        }

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(merged, "Sheet1");
            wb.SaveAs(@"C:___________________.xlsx");
        }
```

I've also taken the liberty of removing a load of extraneous code..

- DataAdapters are wonderful smart things, they don't need anywhere near as much micromanaging as you were doing; just give them an SQL and a connectionstring and tell them to fill a datatable; they know how to set commands, open connections etc on their own
- You don't need to `using` a datatable
- Should your search should look for `*.xlsx` files only?

Comment: Woow! Talk about an elegant solution! and yes i look for xlsx files only. Guess i should change this var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirALC_EDC, "*.xlsx"

Comment: Yup, that's what I'd do

Comment: Hi Caius,  i get a System.out of memory exception, do you think it's related to my PC's RAM?I pasted 6 loops next to each another for my 6 folders containing nearly the same amount of data . I get the first 2 but the code stops running during the execution of the 3rd loop.

Comment: Your datatable object might be growing to more than 2gb? In .net no single object can be larger than this

Comment: Do you think i can try to  insert some random async or await methods in between the loops in order to 'clear' memory if that makes sense.

Comment: I say that because i get the result of the first two loops. I just need a way to reset and restart the code in between loops.

Comment: It sounds like you're coding by trial and error; the short answer is "no, there is nothing you can do to 'clear' memory if you're still keeping reference to it". Stop programming by hit and hope, and sit  back and really think about what the ultimate goal is. If you have huge amounts of rows to be written to an excel file, you should probably think about writing them incrementally and NOT keeping them in memory. You should also consider whether excel is even wise for this task. The whole thing seems like it's outgrowing the limitations your tools of choice will impose